# Gitlab-ci : How to reach dayli automated tests and manual deploying

Tags: angular, gitlab, gitlab-ci

So I have this Angular 6 / Material 6 Application, and I have set up a gitlab around it to handle continuoous integration.

I am not sure how to handle the processing I want :
I mainly need 2 stages : Test and deploy

- Disable gitlab-ci builds on pushes
- Test stage must be triggers dayli by a cron, but this cron must not trigger the deploying
- Deploy stage must be manually triggered, but then Tests should be run, and deploy stage must not be deployed in case of Karma tests failed.

At the moment I got this conf:

```
image: node:8.9.4

stages:
  - test
  - deploy

cache:
  paths:
    - node_modules/

before_script:
  - echo -e [`date "+%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"`] '\E[0;36m=======> Starting before scripts commands'
  - apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y -qq sshpass
  - apt-get --yes install npm
  - echo -e [`date "+%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"`] '\E[0;36m=======> Setting registry to point verdaccio'
  - npm set registry http://192.168.1.20:4873/
  - echo [`date "+%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"`] '//192.168.1.20:4873/:_authToken=${NPM_TOKEN}'>.npmrc
  - apt-get install -yq gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3
    libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4
    libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1
    libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6
    ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
  - echo -e [`date "+%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"`] '\E[0;36m=======> Installing all project libs'
  - npm install

# ********************************************* TESTS STAGE *********************************************
test_stage:
  stage: test
  environment: Staging
  script:
    - echo -e [`date "+%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"`] '\E[0;36m=======> Starting script part for test_stage'
    - npm install
    - ./node_modules/.bin/ng test --karma-config=karma.conf.js --watch=false
  only:
    - master
    - triggers
    # You want a cron to trigger the test build :
    # Include this line to crontab :
    # 0 4 * * * curl -X POST -F token=FOUND_IN_GITLAB -F ref=master -F "variables[IF YOU WANT SOME]=true" http://GITLAB_URL/api/v3/projects/PROJECT_NUMBER/trigger/builds
    # Get token in in gitlab section Triggers
    # Get PROJECT _NUMBER in gitlab section Triggers

  except:
    - pushes

# ********************************************* DEPLOY STAGE *********************************************
deploy_stage:
  stage: deploy
  environment: Staging
  only:
    - master

  script:
    - echo -e [`date "+%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"`] '\E[0;36m=======> Starting script part for deploy_stage'
    - echo -e [`date "+%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"`] '\E[0;36m=======> Compiling with NG BUILD'
    - ./node_modules/.bin/ng build --configuration=recette --prod
    - sshpass -V
    - export SSHPASS=$USER_PASS
    - echo -e [`date "+%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"`] '\E[0;36m=======> Deleting everything in archive folder'
    - sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USER@XX.XX.XX.XX -pPORT "rm -rf /CHEMIN_ARCHIVE/archive/*"
    - echo -e [`date "+%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"`] '\E[0;36m=======> Copying server files into archive folder'
    - sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USER@XX.XX.XX.XX -pPORT "cp -a /CHEMIN_SERVER/server/. /CHEMIN_ARCHIVEt/archive/"
    - echo -e [`date "+%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"`] '\E[0;36m=======> Deleting everything in server folder'
    - sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USER@XX.XX.XX.XX -pPORT "rm -rf /CHEMIN_SERVER/server/*"
    - echo -e [`date "+%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"`] '\E[0;36m=======> Sending dist folder to livraison folder'
    - sshpass -e scp -P PORT -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -r ./dist USER@XX.XX.XX.XX:/CHEMIN_LIVRAISON/livraison
    - echo -e [`date "+%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"`] '\E[0;36m=======> Copying livraison files to server folder'
    - sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USER@XX.XX.XX.XX -pPORT "cp -a /CHEMIN_LIVRAISON/livraison/. /CHEMIN_SERVER/server/"
    - echo -e [`date "+%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S"`] '\E[0;36m=======> Deleting everything in livraison folder'
    - sshpass -e ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no USER@XX.XX.XX.XX -pPORT "rm -rf /CHEMIN_LIVRAISON/livraison/*"
  when: manual
```

But as you can see, when : manual is working.
Meaning the cron triggers the build, it plays the Tests stage and then skip the deploy phase :

[image]

Of course, as planned I can trigger manually this deploy phase, but it would then not trigger the tests.

So how could I get to the target : When I trigger the deploy build manually, It would be great if tests could be run, and if tests fails, the deploying shoul not be launched ?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
stages:
- test
- deploy

.test-template: &test-definition
  image: alpine:3.6
  stage: test
  script:
  - bash launch_test.sh

trigger-test:
  <<: *test-definition
  only:
  - triggers

manual-test:
  <<: *test-definition
  when: manual
  only:
  - master
  allow_failure: false

deploy:
  image: alpine:3.6
  stage: deploy
  script:
  - bash deploy.sh
  only:
  - master
  dependencies:
  - manual-test
```

You start manually `manual-test` job and if it succeeds `deploy` job is launched.

You can also triggered `trigger-test` to launch only the tests.

Comment: Many thank for answering, I am gonna test this, and as soon as I see it working, I'll validate your solution ! :D

Comment: DIdn't have the chance to test this :( BUt I will as soon as possible. Validating this As what your describing is exactly what I am trying to reach :) Thanks a lot.